# Pivot Table only reading first two rows of my data and not processing the rest

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a sheet in excel with columns for year, school, student group, # in cohort, %Graduated, and %Dropped out. I copy and pasted the data from several tables in a web browser into excel, and then took the columns and rows I wanted and pasted them from there into my master sheet. When I went to make a pivot table I found that only the first two rows were being read and everything else was showing as 0(There are no zeros in the raw data) unless I used the count function within the pivot which correctly identified the number of populated cells in each column.

I have tried pasting the table as values only into a new workbook and sheet as well as changed formatting for each column but the issue persists. Another strange thing is that when I change formatting for a column from general to number it adds 2 decimal places only to the first two rows as well.

Comment: Your data is stored as text, which is why it won't sum. There may be extraneous characters such as non-breaking spaces that prevent it being seen as real numbers - hard to say without the actual file.

Comment: Absolutely agreed what @Rory Sir has said, it can text or there can be non-printable characters, but this latter one depends on the source you have downloaded from, the prior may be a human error.

Comment: It was because of the spaces! somehow a space character got added to each cell's value in the pasting process. Thank you so much!